# Syncing CRM 2011 and SharePoint Security

Tags: security, sharepoint-2010, synchronization, dynamics-crm-2011

I have integrated our SharePoint site and our Dynamics CRM 2011 system so that we can upload documents from CRM. But i had a thought that through security in CRM users can only see records relevant to them, but if they just went to the SharePoint site they'll be able to see documents related to any record even if they couldn't see it in CRM.

So i was wondering if its possible in some way to 'sync' the security from CRM into SharePoint so that users can't see what they're not meant to in either system.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible out of the box. SharePoint's security model is usually based on AD groups, whilst CRM uses in-app security roles applied per user.

To keep these in sync would require some custom development on the server side, that is if it's possible at all.

Comment: If it is possible to develop some custom tool to do this, would that be as a general read/write access to all folders or is it possible to only give access to certain folders? I'm not really sure on how SharePoint security works

Comment: I'm not an expert on the intracacies of SharePoint security, so I'm not really qualified to comment - however I would suggest that if you can implement SharePoint security in a way that satisfies your requirements you *should* be able to then use a Plugin to automatically allocate that security to users based on their CRM security. How would you actually implement this? No idea, sorry.

Comment: No worries, you've been very helpful and i think i've got an idea how i can do it. Thanks

Comment: Rossp, does that mean SharePoint security is pinned to Active Directory users ONLY (e.g. not users in Claims Based Auth under SQL Server membership)?

Comment: @AshesToAshes I'm not sure, sorry - as mentioned above I'm not a SharePoint expert and don't know much about it's authentication. Sorry for the late response :(

Answer (score 5):

It is possible out-of-the-box. There is a commercial [CB Replicator](https://www.connecting-software.com/dynamics-crm-sharepoint-permissions-replicator/) solution that solves exactly this problem. It performs complex mapping of CRM security model into SharePoint groups and and folder level permissions.

Shortly described it deploys tiny plugin into CRM that collects all the events that could require change of permissions. There is a standalone service that gets these events and write proper permissions into SharePoint as item level permissions on referenced folders by sharepointdocumentlocation entity.

It support various action in CRM that lead into permissions change, e.g.s security roles, business unit hierarchy, privilege depths, team membership, access team, access team templates, sharing.